# Know if an @output event is binded in the parent component

Tags: angular

I have an `@Output labelClicked = new EventEmitter();` and I want to know if this event has been binded in the parent component (with `<myComponent (labelClicked)="open($event)"></myComponent>`) so I can style my component with a `cursor: pointer`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Solution :**

```
<span class="label" [class.clickable]="labelClicked.observers.length > 0">{{label}}</span>
```

( css : `.clickable { cursor: pointer; }` )

**Explaination :**

As per my understand you want to detect if the event handler attached with the component or not. if it's attached you want to add some class else no need to attach the class.

i just did the quick check actually angular @output variable hold the info about how many handler attached with the event

[image]

[image]

in that above image i have attached handler with submit event and close event dont have any handler attached. so you can check this array and assign class using render

Answer (score 4):

Using the accepted answer, my IDE tells me:

> "Internal implementation detail, do not use directly. Will be made
> internal in v8."

I found that you can use:

```js
    labelClicked.observed
```

instead of:

```js
    labelClicked.observers.length > 0
```

FYI, this is the internal implementation of `observed` within `Subject.ts` (so it makes sense that this works)

```js
  get observed() {
    return this.observers?.length > 0;
  }
```